# Asp.net Razorpage: Eventhandler on Checkbox is not firing

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, razor

I am trying to react to state changes of my checkbox:

```
                                                <td>
                                                    @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.checkLangs[0].isChecked, new { onchange = "checkedChanged" })


                                                    <script>
                                                        var checkedChanged = function () {
                                                            alert("checkedChanged");
                                                        }
                                                    </script>

                                                </td>
```

But unfortunaltey, I do see the checkbox but I do not see the alert.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use `onchange = "checkedChanged()"`,and you'd better don't put script into `<td></td>`:

```
    <td>
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.checkLangs[0].isChecked, new { onchange = "checkedChanged()" })

    </td>
    ...
    <script>
            var checkedChanged = function () {      
                 alert("checkedChanged");
            }
    </script>
```

Comment: I dont really see that is different to what I already did excpet for u moved the script tag outside the <td>. Or am I blind? ^^

Comment: Please pay attention to your code,you use `onchange = "checkedChanged"`.I test with the code,when using `onchange = "checkedChanged"`,the js will not be firing,but use `onchange = "checkedChanged()"`.